# How to setup WiFi AP with ac,n and g bands and bridge with ethernet port

Tags: wireless, 16.04, network-bridge

How to setup Ubuntu 16.04 to install WiFi AP with ac, n and g bands with latest cards in the market today. And also how can I bridge it to my Ethernet port which has internet connection?

I have seen few examples of g band setup and they do work till you setup AP but nothing beyond that.

Thanks for looking into it.